# jQuery Div Animation - Show w/ URL

Tags: javascript, html

I have Divs show and hide (with an animation) using the following script (I included the jQuery library)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function ShowHide(){
$("#info").animate({"height": "toggle"}, { duration: 1000 });
}
//]]>
</script>
```

I activate the showing/hiding with 
`<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Hide Message"onclick="ShowHide(); return false;" />` or similar (for a text link, I do `href="#" onclick="ShowHide(); return false;"`.

All of that works fine, but I want to know how to make it so I can have a div show with a URL.  What I mean is that I want to be able to have users go to example.com/?show=test (or similar) and have the div called "test" show.

It really doesn't have to use the same script as above.  What I mainly want to use it for is to show a Thank you message for filling out a feedback form show on the homepage in a little box.

Thanks in advance for the help.  (I can clarify anything if it was confusing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always parse out the ID of the div from the query string, or more simply use a hash instead, i.e., `example.com#test`. Then you could just do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var whichDiv = location.hash.split('#')[1];
    $('#' + whichDiv).show();
});
```

You can always just calls `show` directly on the `location.hash`, since the raw value begins with the '#' character anyway:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var whichDiv = location.hash;
    $(whichDiv).show();
});
```

If you *really* need to parse out the `show` parameter:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var whichDiv = $.url.param("show");
    $(whichDiv).show();
});
```

The above example makes use of [this tiny jQuery URL plugin](http://ajaxcssblog.com/jquery/url-read-request-variables/).

Comment: This is the right way to do it in JS, but in general, this sounds like something that's better done on the server side, since the OP seems to be reloading the page anyway.

Comment: @Max Shawabkeh - totally agree. On the server side, if the `show` parameter is not set, set the div's style to `display:none`, otherwise reveal it.